# Сравнение и вывод данных (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

Помогите пожалуйста сравнить и вывести только нужные данные.

Код который указан ниже отображает все записи из таблицы me_cars.

Мне нужно сравнить данные из таблицы me_cars (item_city) и me_place (place_city)

Например если я нахожусь на странице контроллера place (/place/place_title), у которой place_city = 58, то вывести на странице из таблицы me_cars, записи у которых item_city равняется 58.

Сейчас если я нахожусь на странице контроллера place (/place/place_title), с данным кодом выводятся все данные из таблицы me_cars, т.е. полностью все записи списком.

Нужно чтобы перед выводом была проверка, если открыта страница /place/place_title1 и у нее place_city = 58, отобразить данные из me_cars только с item_city = 58.

Если открыта страница /place/place_title2  и у нее в таблице в place_city = 43, отобразить данные из me_cars только с item_city = 43. и т.д.

Спасибо.

Controller

```
$this->data['lastitem'] = $this->item_model->get_lastitem();
```

Model

```
function get_lastitem() {

    $this->db->select('me_cars.item_id,me_cars.item_slug,me_cars.item_city,me_locations.location as location,me_cars.item_title,me_cars.item_order,MIN(me_extras.extra_basic_price) as price');

    $this->db->order_by("item_id", "desc");
    $this->db->group_by('me_cars.item_id');
    $this->db->join('me_extras', 'me_cars.item_id = me_extras.extra_item', 'left');
    $this->db->join('me_locations', 'me_cars.item_city = me_locations.id', 'left');

    $query = $this->db->get('me_cars');
    return $query->result_array();              
}
```

View

```
<?php foreach ($lastitem as $item){ ?>          
        <?php echo $item['item_title'];?>
        <?php echo $item['price'];?>
        <!-- содержимое ... -->
<?php } ?>
```

**Таблица me_cars:**

```
| item_title | item_city | 
+------------+-------------+
| Title item | 25        |
+------------+-------------+
| Title item | 58        |
+------------+-------------+
| Title item | 43        |
+------------+-------------+
| Title item | 58        |
+------------+-------------+
| Title item | 43        |
+------------+-------------+
```

**Таблица me_place:**

```
| place_title | place_city | 
+--------------+--------------+
| Title place | 25           |
+--------------+--------------+
| Title place | 58           |
+--------------+--------------+
| Title place | 43           |
+--------------+--------------+
| Title place | 58           |
+--------------+--------------+
| Title place | 43           |
+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Попробуйте сформулировать понятнее. Что значит "сравнить все записи", "нахожусь на странице"? приведите структуру таблиц (желательно убрать все ненужное, не относящееся непосредственно к вопросу. По сути - на первый взгляд у вас в модели не хватает условия в запросе: `$this->db->where('item_city', $item_city);` но что-куда-зачем разобраться по вопросу непросто.

Comment: Добрый день! Поправил вопрос, и добавил структуру таблиц

Answer (score 1):

router:

```
$route['place/(:any)'] = 'public/place/$1';
```

controller Public:

```
function place ($title)
{
    $data['item'] = $this->model_item->get_item_by_title($title);
}
```

model:

```
function get_item_by_title($title)
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
        // берем данные из таблицы me_place
        ->from('me_place')
        // только те, у которых place_title = $title
        ->where('place_title', $title)
        // связываем с таблицей me_cars чтобы place_city=item_city
        // LEFT нужен для того, чтобы если в БД нет записей с искомым item_city
        // все равно вернулась одна строка с данными из таблицы me_place
        // но в item_city будет стоять NULL
        ->join('me_cars', 'me_title.place_city = me_cars.item_city', 'LEFT')
        ->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

связи с `me_extras` и `me_locations` из вашего примера я опустил, потому как сейчас не имеют значения.

---

UPD по просьбе из комментов:

Можно сделать два отдельных запроса: первым получить `place_city` по известному вам `place_title`:

```
$query = $this->db->select('place_city')
    ->from('me_place')
    ->where('place_title', $title)
    ->limit(1)
    ->get();
// пишу по памяти, проверьте в доке как получить только первую запись
$place_city = $query->row()->place_city;
```

А вторым запросом уже то, что нужно вам:

```
$query = $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('me_cars')
    ->where('item_city', $place_city)
    ->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Разумеется, все проверки на непустые значения из БД я опустил, для краткости.

Comment: У меня получилось вручную вывести, если просто добавить $this->db->where('item_city', 58); В данном случае выводятся только записи с item_city = 58. Можно ли как-то подставить вместо 58 (в запросе), значение из place_city?

Comment: обновил свой ответ

Comment: оффтопик-совет: я сам долго сидел на codeigniter, но недавно уперся в потолок, плюнул и ушел в fuelphp. попробуйте, он вырос из CI но совсем другой. в нём больше стиля и красоты, и при этом он такой же лёгкий. потом придется переучиваться.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, буду пробовать. По Ci просто уже многое сделано на сайте и нереально все переписывать. Но на будущие сайты учту. Спасибо